# Is a Croatian visa needed if I have a valid multiple-entry Schengen visa and I enter Croatia first?

Tags: visas, paperwork, filipino-citizens, visa-free-entry, croatia

I'm Filipino and will be travelling to Budapest September 5 to 10 (6 days) and will secure a Schengen visa. Before entry to Budapest, I will travel first to Croatia and will be arriving in Zagreb on August 31. So I have 5 days around  Croatia.

Do I need to get a Croatian visa?

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is not 100% correct.

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a double or multiple
>   entry C visa issued by a Schengen Member State valid for all Schengen Member States and valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days.

So if you have a double- or multiple-entry Schengen visa, you can enter Croatia on it, even before visiting the Schengen Area

You shouldn't assume you'll receive a double/multiple-entry visa, however (unless you've received one in the past), and if you only get a single-entry visa, then a Croatian visa is required as well.

Comment: Yes I usually get a multiple entry Schengen visa every year I travel for several years already, so hopefully this time I will also get that. Thank you